# Derivative of function with respect to matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

## Problem

I would like to compute the derivatives with respect to $U$ and $V$ of this function
$$
f(U, V) = \|Y - XUV^\top\|_F^2 + \lambda\|UV^\top\|_F^2.
$$

## Notation

Let $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $U\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times d}$, $V\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times d}$ and $\lambda > 0$.

## Attempted Solution for $U$

Using the matrix cookbook I get for the first term
$$
\begin{align}
    \nabla_U \|Y - XUV^\top||_F^2 
&= \nabla_U \text{Tr}((Y - XUV^\top)^\top(Y-XUV^\top)) \\
&= \text{Tr}(Y^\top Y -Y^\top XUV^\top - VU^\top X^\top Y - V U^\top X^\top X U V^\top) \\
&= -2X^\top Y V + \nabla_U\text{Tr}(VU^\top X^\top X UV^\top) \\
&= -2X^\top Y V + 2 X^\top X U V^\top V
\end{align}
$$
Using equations 101, 102 and 116 of the Matrix Cookbook. Using again equation 116 for the second term we have
$$
\nabla_U \lambda \|UV^\top\|_F^2 = \lambda \nabla_U \text{Tr}(VU^\top U V^\top) = 2\lambda U V^\top V
$$
so overall we have
$$
\nabla_U f(U, V) = -2X^\top Y V + 2 X^\top X U V^\top V + 2\lambda U V^\top V
$$

## Attempted Solution for V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful computer algebra tool for these kinds of problems is [www.matrixcalculus.org](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/).

Simply enter `norm2(Y-X*U*V')^2 + c*norm2(U*V')^2` and you get:

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{(I)}&&\frac{\partial}{\partial U} \left( \|Y-X U V^\top \|_2^{2}+c \|U V^\top \|_2^{2} \right) 
&= 2 c U V^\top  V-2 X^\top \cdot (Y-X U V^\top ) V
\\ \text{(II)}&& \frac{\partial}{\partial V} \left( \|Y-X U V^\top \|_2^{2}+c \|U V^\top \|_2^{2} \right) 
&= 2 c V U^\top  U-2 (Y^\top -V U^\top  X^\top ) X U
\end{aligned}$$

---

Now, if you want to derive this stuff by hand, two simple rules you can remember are:

1. $AXB^⊤ = (A⊗B)⋅X$. In particular, $\frac{∂ AXB^⊤}{∂X} = A⊗B$

   - **Note1:** $A⊗B≔(A_{ik}B_{jl})_{ij, kl}$ is a rank-4 tensor, and $(A⊗B)⋅X$ denotes the tensor-contraction $∑_{kl}(A⊗B)_{ij, kl} X_{kl}$ (convince yourself that this is the same as $AXB^⊤$!)
   - **Note2:** matrixcalculus.org follows the different convention $AXB^⊤ = (B⊗A)⋅X$, the results are the same anyway!
2. $\frac{∂ \frac{1}{2}\|⋅X -Y\|^2}{∂X} = ^⊤(⋅X-Y)$. In particular:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{∂ \frac{1}{2}\|AXB^⊤\|^2}{∂X} 
&= \frac{∂ \frac{1}{2}\|(A⊗B)⋅X\|^2}{∂X}
\\&= (A⊗B)^⊤(A⊗B)⋅X 
\\&= (A^⊤⊗B^⊤)(A⊗B)⋅X
\\&= (A^⊤A⊗B^⊤B)⋅X
\\&= A^⊤A X B^⊤B
\end{aligned}$$

So for instance we get

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{∂½\|Y-X U V^⊤ \|^2}{∂V}
&=\frac{∂½\|Y-X U V^⊤ \|^2}{∂V^\top}\frac{∂V^⊤}{∂V}
\\&=\frac{∂½\|(X U⊗)⋅ V^⊤\|^2}{∂V^\top}\frac{∂V^⊤}{∂V}
\\&=(X U⊗)^⊤((X U⊗)⋅V^⊤-Y)⋅
\\&=\big((U^⊤X^⊤XU⊗)V^⊤ - (U^⊤X^⊤⊗)Y\big)⋅
\\&=(U^⊤X^⊤XUV -U^⊤X^⊤Y) ⋅
\\&=VU^⊤X^⊤XU - Y^⊤ XU
\end{aligned}$$

Which you will recognize as the second term in (II). Here, $$ is the so-called **transpose tensor** which satisfies $⋅X = X^⊤$.

Comment: That website looks amazing!

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Introduce the matrix variable
$$Z=UV^T\qiq dZ=dU\,V^T + U\,dV^T$$
and the matrix inner product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Rewrite the function in terms of these and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \LR{XZ-Y}:\LR{XZ-Y} + \l\LR{Z:Z} \\
df &= 2\LR{XZ-Y}:\LR{X\,dZ} + 2\l\LR{Z:dZ} \\
 &= \BR{2X^T\LR{XZ-Y} + 2\l Z}:dZ \\
 &= G:dZ \\
}$$
where $G$ is the gradient with respect to $Z$.

If $V$ is constant, then $\,dV=0\;$ and
$$\eqalign{
dZ &= dU\,V^T \qiq df = G:dU\,V^T = GV:dU \qiq \g{f}{U} = GV \\
}$$
while if $U$ is constant
$$\eqalign{
dZ &= U\,dV^T \qiq df = G:U\,dV^T = G^TU:dV \qiq \g{f}{V} = G^TU \\\\
}$$

---

**NB:** $\,$ The properties of the underlying trace function allow terms in the matrix inner product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
}$$